# Create solid 3D shape in p5.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, processing, p5.js

I am trying to make an apple surface in 3D using in p5.js, similar as the images on [this page](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/spherical/) (Ctrl+F "Apple Surface"):

[image: apple surface wireframe]

[image: apple surface filled].

What I currently have is ([interactive version in p5 editor](https://editor.p5js.org/BioGeek/sketches/5Ggx83zj8)):

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500, WEBGL);
  setAttributes('antialias', true);
  fill(237, 34, 93);
  strokeWeight(3);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  normalMaterial();
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateZ(frameCount * 0.01);
  apple();
}


function apple() {
  beginShape(TRIANGLE_FAN);

  size = 20;

  for (let u = 0; u < TWO_PI; u += 0.1) {
      for (let v = -PI; v < PI; v += 0.1) {
    x = cos(u) * (4 + 3.8 * cos(v))
    y = sin(u) * (4 + 3.8 * cos(v))     
    z = (cos(v) + sin(v) -1) * (1+sin(v)) * log(1-PI * v/10)+7.5 * sin(v)
    //point(size * x, size * y, size * z);
    vertex(size * x, size * y, size * z);
      }
  }

  endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

How do I make my shape solid as in the second apple picture above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create triangle strip primitives (`TRIANGLE_STRIP` - see [`beginShape()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/beginShape)):

```
0        2       4        6
 +-------+-------+-------+---
 | \     | \     | \     | \
 |   \   |   \   |   \   |   \
 |     \ |     \ |     \ |
 +-------+-------+-------+---
1        3       5        7
```

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500, WEBGL);
  setAttributes('antialias', true);
  fill(237, 34, 93);
  strokeWeight(3);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  normalMaterial();
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateZ(frameCount * 0.01);
  apple();
}

function apple() {

  size = 20;
  for (let u = 0; u < TWO_PI; u += 0.1) {
      beginShape(TRIANGLE_STRIP);
      for (let v = -PI; v < PI; v += 0.1) {
        x = cos(u) * (4 + 3.8 * cos(v))
        y = sin(u) * (4 + 3.8 * cos(v))     
        z = (cos(v) + sin(v) -1) * (1+sin(v)) * log(1-PI * v/10)+7.5 * sin(v)
        vertex(size * x, size * y, size * z);

        x = cos(u+0.1) * (4 + 3.8 * cos(v))
        y = sin(u+0.1) * (4 + 3.8 * cos(v)) 
        vertex(size * x, size * y, size * z);
      }
      endShape(CLOSE);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```